# I want to add font to my JPanel and all of its components. (like labels and text fields and password fields)

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jframe, jpanel

I used to `setFont` for labels and text fields one by one. But later on, when my project has more and more labels and text fields it's a headache. So, I was wondering if I could apply the font to the whole panel at once.

I tried to do this :

```
panel1 = new JPanel();

panel1.add(new JLabel("Registration ID : "));
panel1.add(new JTextField(" your text "));
panel1.add(new JLabel("Name : "));
panel1.setFont(font1);
```

Comment: Fonts for entire classes of components can be set via the `UIManager` or a custom PLAF. Given you're new to programming though, I'd recommend focusing on other things. Changing fonts will not improve the layout or functionality of software. BTW *"..and password fields"* a password field is meant to display 'dots' in place of alphabetic or numeric characters, so changing the font (family at least) will not make much difference.

Answer (score 0):

An easy (but not necessarily best practice) way of solving this, is to traverse the `Component` hierarchy of the `panel1` recursively and set the font, like so:

```
public static void consumeRecursive(final Container container,
                                    final Consumer<Component> consumer) {
    for (final Component child: container.getComponents()) {
        if (child instanceof Container)
            consumeRecursive((Container) child, consumer);
        else
            consumer.accept(child);
    }
    consumer.accept(container);
}
```

And then use like in the below snippet:

```
final Font font = new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 45); //Change with your desired font...
consumeRecursive(panel1, c -> c.setFont(font));
```

This will set the `Font` of **every** component in the existing hierarchy (with `panel1` as the root).

Note: the call to `consumeRecursive` should be done after you add to it all children (and the children of those, etc...), ie first create the whole hierarchy of `panel1` and then call `consumeRecursive` like in the above example. That is only if you want all children to be modified.